# Why request queuing is high even when request executing is below its limit?

Tags: .net, performance, performancecounter, act

Why request queuing is high even when request executing is below its limit?

We are using below settings

- Target Framework : .Net 3.5 Framework
- Application Pool :.Net Framework v2.0.50727 with Managed pipeline mode – Integrated
- And, no of CPU is 8 so maxconcurrentRequestperCPUx8=96
- RAM : 24 GB

With Default Settings in machine.config and aspnet.config

We did testing with ACT and took performance counters.

ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727(_LM_W3SVC_2_ROOT)\Requests Executing

[image]

ASP.NET v2.0.50727\Requests Queued

[image]

Now we made below changes

In aspnet.config

```
 <system.web>
      <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="5000" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000"/>
 </system.web>
```

In machine.config

```
<system.web>
    <processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="4095" maxIoThreads="4095"    minWorkerThreads="2047" minIoThreads="2047" />
</system.web>
```

And provide Application Pool Queue Limit=5000
Now we have very less request queuing comparatively and high request executing as below snapshots depicts!!

ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727(_LM_W3SVC_2_ROOT)\Requests Executing

[image]

ASP.NET v2.0.50727\Requests Queued

[image]

But surprisingly avg. response time per seconds in ACT has not improved.

[image]

So I have below questions…

**1)  Why there is request queuing even when request executing is below its limit (in my case no. of CPU x maxconcurrentrequestperCPU = 8 x 12 = 96)?**

2)  Even making changes to aspnet.config, machine.config and providing Application Pool Queue Limit=5000, why request queuing is observed?

3)  Why ACT response time has not improved as Request Executing Counter is higher?

Any help is appreciated !!

Thanks,

Sandeepkumar Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did everything as described by [Thomas L. Marquardt](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/) and you even increased minWorkerThreads and minIoThreads.

There is an interesting piece regarding connectionManagement/maxconnection which may be affecting you

> In general, running with default configuration works best.  However,
>   applications that have measurable latency, say latency of 100
>   milliseconds when communicating with a backend web service, will
>   perform better with a few configuration changes.

He then recommends

> If your ASP.NET application is using web services (WFC or ASMX) or
>   System.Net to communicate with a backend over HTTP you may need to
>   increase connectionManagement/maxconnection.  For ASP.NET
>   applications, this is limited to 12 * #CPUs by the autoConfig feature.
>   This means that on a quad-proc, you can have at most 12 * 4 = 48
>   concurrent connections to an IP end point.

And sadly he adds

> If your application sees a large number of concurrent requests at start-up or has a bursty load, where concurrency increases suddenly,
>   you will need to make the application asynchronous because the CLR
>   ThreadPool does not respond well to these loads.